# Convert a series of If to R.cond correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ramda.js

I have a series of If statements. I want to convert them to Ramda's conditional, but I get this errors, that Never is not assigned to Element. So, obviously I am doing something wrong:

```
  if (cond1) return <Comp1 />;
  if (cond2) return <Comp2 />;
  if (cond3) return <Comp3 />;

  return <CompFinalGaurd />;
```

And here is what I did:

```
R.cond([
    [cond1, () => <Comp1 />],
    [cond2, () => <Comp2 />],
    [cond3, () => <Comp3 />],
    [R.T, () => <CompFinalGaurd />],
  ]);
```

What am I doing wrong? My screen isn't loading cause I think the `cond` isn't returning a valid React Element. But how to fix it? Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use the same expressions for `cond1`, `cond2`, ... in both snippets, then I understand the problem.

Ramda's [`cond`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) takes predicate functions, not boolean expressions.  And it returns a function that you need to call to do anything useful.

Thus this expression

```js
cond ([
  [predicate1, consequent1],
  [predicate2, consequent2],
  [predicate3, consequent3],
  [T, finalGuard],
])
```

takes *functions* for both the predicates and the consequents.  It passes the same arguments to each.  It's essentially equivalent to

```
(...args) =>
  predicate1 (...args)
    ? consequent1 (...args)
  : predicate2 (...args)
    ? consequent2 (...args)
  : predicate3 (...args)
    ? consequent3 (...args)
  : T (...args)
    ? finalGuard (...args) 
    : undefined  // won't hit this since the final predicate always returns `true`
```

It sounds like this would explain your problem.  If not, please post additional details.

(Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tbh, Ramda is an amazing tool, but a bit too functional sometimes for me, thus my misunderstandings. Thanks for your help. Your answer helped a lot.